# Setting default character encoding for all jsps in a Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, tomcat7

Strange scenario here.

I have a Java Web Application which supports UTF-8 characters. That is they display and can be entered on the application

I also have another application which accesses the previous one as below basic snippet

```
final URL urlObject = new URL("someurlyadayada");
final URLConnection connection = urlObject.openConnection(); 
...
....
connection.connect(); 
final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8");
final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(somelocalfile));
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out,"UTF8");

int read = 0;

while ((read = isr.read()) != -1) {
    osw.write(read);
    }
....
```

When a given page is viewed in browser everything renders fine UTF-8 characters and all. But when using the above snippet characters are corrupted either coming back as *???????* or just the wrong characters.

What I have tried so far is setting the encoding to UTF-8 on the input/output stream writers and also on the request and response objects in the app.

This partially works in that given a JPS with the following lines

```
Прочтено Прочтено,Прочтено,
<%=someJavaMethodWhichReturnsTheAboveLineAlso()%>
```

In the browser this renders fine as:

> Прочтено Прочтено,Прочтено,
>
> Прочтено Прочтено,Прочтено,

But using the page parser will return

> Ð¾ÑÑÐµÐ½Ð¾ ÐÑÐ¾ÑÑÐµÐ½Ð¾ÑÐ¾ÑÑÐµÐ½Ð¾ ÐÑÐ¾ÑÑÐµÐ½Ð¾
>
> Прочтено Прочтено,Прочтено,

If I set `contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"` on top of all my pages JSPs it fixes both issues but I have been told by higher ups that updating  100s of JSPs to have this is not possible.

I also get the impression this is something I should be able to set once and use it as default.

What's best practice here. I'm of two minds about setting the content on the JSP's. Not sure if this is wrong to do or we're wrong to never have done it in the first place.

I've had a good look around for solutions and had mixed success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the default Character Encoding for all JSPs on the web.xml file, that way it's done globally

```
<jsp-config>   
    <jsp-property-group id="defaultUtf8Encoder">
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>     
</jsp-config>
```

What you can also do, is to create a Filter which sets the response character encoding (and eventually content type), as such: (below the example does the character encoding)

```
public class CharsetFilter
  implements Filter {

  String encoding = "UTF-8";

  public void destroy() {
    /* Do nothing */
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
         ServletResponse response,
         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);        
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {       
  }
}
```

Then you define the filter in the web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>
        charsetFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        your.filter.package.CharsetFilter
    </filter-class>        
</filter>                                         

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Notice that I'm applying the filter to /* which uses any web app resource. This may be handy if you want the filter to affect every single web resource

Hopefully that should sort you out

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment. This in addition to my other changes(The input/output streams does seem to be working. I had forgotten I had added code elsewhere that was trying to set the content type. Once i removed my code it worked.